# Making a reasonable slab of alpha quartz

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I want to perform a molecular dynamics simulation with alpha-quartz as my mineral surface. I want to study adsorption of water on alpha-quartz. The most dominant error that I came up with is the problem with my initial physical configuration. In other words error is: System is too far from equilibrium. I think the major problem is related to chemical structure of alpha-quartz slab.

I used the experimental data for unit cell of alpha quartz and then replicate it for making a slab of it. My question is: Is this structure stressed in some way? My cell is periodic in 3 directions and some of oxygen atoms are not in the right place! Can it be the problem?

How to replicate unit cell of alpha quartz for obtaining a reasonable structure? Where can I find a right data for unit cell of alpha quartz?

Comment: 1) it is normal for a surface made from slicing of infinite crystal structure to be far from equilibrium. It usually undergoes significant reconstruction, with formation of new bonds and reaction with molecules from gas phase. Read relevant articles/books. 2)it is common to fix several layers of slab from side opposite to surface modeled.  3) alfa-quartz is a bad case for case study for work with crystal surfaces. It has a really, really wicked structure. I recommend to try some more studied system first, like MgO or gold surface.

Comment: Thank you permeakra, I will take your advice into consideration.

Comment: BTW, it is normal to have ~5% difference in simulated parameters from each other and real life for QC simulation.